# (Simple?) Pivot Example

Tags: t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm having trouble with trying to figure out what I think should be a pretty basic pivot. I've tried searching here and elsewhere for something like "simple pivot example", but I'm finding that most of the examples are not quite simple enough for my caveman brain.

I have 2 `INT` columns in a table, say `col1` and `col2`. The values for `col1` are `2` through `10`. The values for `col2` are `1` through `5`.

My desired output is this:

```
         col2_1    col2_2    col2_3    col2_4    col2_5
 col1_2    10        5         2          6         7
 col1_3     8        6         3         22        12
    ...
col1_10    20        2         0          3        90
```

Where each value represents the number of occurrences (`count`) of `col1_2 x col2_1`,  `col1_3 x col2_1`, and so on.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    col1_2,
    col1_3,
    col1_4,
    col1_5,
    col1_6,
    col1_7,
    col1_8,
    col1_9,
    col1_10'    
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            col1,
            col2
        FROM
            data_table
    ) AS tSource
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(col2)
    FOR col1 IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
) AS tPivoted
```

but it's not correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    'col1_'+cast(col1 as varchar(2)), 
    isnull([1],0) [col2_1],
    isnull([2],0) [col2_2],  
    isnull([3],0) [col2_3], 
    isnull([4],0) [col2_4], 
    isnull([5],0) [col2_5]
  FROM
  (Select col1, col2, Count(1) as cnt from table1
    GROUP BY col1, col2) as tSource
  PIVOT
  (
    SUM(cnt)
    FOR COL2 in ([1],[2], [3], [4], [5])
  ) as tPivoted
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. This gets sort of close, but not quite there. This gives me columns named `col1_2`, `col1_3`, etc. and the values are counts for all values of `col2`. I'm trying to get `col1_2 x col2_1`, `col1_3 x col2_1`, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are trying to multiply the results of the pivot?

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of times: `col1` = `2` where `col2` = `1`, `col1` = `3` where `col2` = `1`, ... `col1` = `10` where `col2` = `5`. I tried to show this in my example desired output above.

Comment: Great thanks, Steve! If you update your answer I'll accept it. Also, if you don't mind explaining the `Count(1) as cnt` part I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I updated the answer.  The count(1) simply counts the records that match the group by clause.  It would be the same as using count(col2), just a different way to get to the same end.